# SQL - Selecting Row Ranges

Tags: sql

Just want to ask for some advise on something that is boggling me.

For example, the table "customers" has 10,000 rows, if we are to select the first half, we can do select top(5000) * from customers, but what if we need to select the next 5000 rows?

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: Use `order by` and do descending

Comment: What RMDBS are you using?

Comment: depends on the RDBMS... Access & SQL Server use `SELECT TOP 5000 ...`, MySQL uses `SELECT ... LIMIT 5000`, Oracle uses `SELECT ... WHERE ROWNUM <= 5000`. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp). Of course you'd need to order your rows somehow (at the very least by primary key)

Comment: With relational databases, you shouldn't think about "first 10" and "next 5" or "first half" and "last half". What you have is a set of data. You can reduce it down to a specific subset that you are interested in. Then you can `order by` to place it in a particular sequence. But the data itself has no inherent order, and you shouldn't think of it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Do an order by and sort it in Descending.

Answer (score 0):

If your table has exactly 10,000 rows, then yes, `TOP 5000` gives you the first 5000 normally, and the last 5000 if you `ORDER BY ... DESCENDING`.

However the general case is when you have hundreds of thousands of rows and you want them 5000 at a time. This is when you need some way to page.

In general you need an integer row counter that you can compare to various 5000 ranges to get a page.  This may be an actual column in your table that contains a row number that counts from 1 to maxcustomer; if so you are good:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 5000
   ORDER BY CustomerNumber
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerNumber BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000
   ORDER BY CustomerBumber
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerNumber BETWEEN 10001 AND 15000
   ORDER BY CustomerBumber
```

(Remember, a SELECT has no defined order unless you give an `ORDER BY` clause!)

If you don't, then (depending on your SQL system) you can generate one using windowed SQL99 functions:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CustomerNumber) AS RN
     FROM CUSTOMERS ) AS X WHERE X.RN BETWEEN 1 AND 5000
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CustomerNumber) AS RN
     FROM CUSTOMERS ) AS X WHERE X.RN BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CustomerNumber) AS RN
     FROM CUSTOMERS ) AS X WHERE X.RN BETWEEN 10001 AND 15000
```

A third way is to look at the last CustomerNumber returned by the previous call, and use it to set up the next call:

```
SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY CustomerNumber
-- the app then captures the last number and feeds it back:
SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerNumber > nnnn
```

This last way may be the most efficient, in fact, given a decent index on CustomerNumber.

Comment: you cannot reference row_number() directly in the where clause (for the rdbms's I'm familiar with) you need a nested subquery then you can reference the output of it in the where clause of the outer query.